# Recording a data value from time.perf_counter?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a very simple reaction time game just for practice with Python.

I've got the game itself set up, it works relatively well and does what I want it to. Here's the code:

```
import time, random, tkinter

x = 1

for x in range(0,10):

    print("Dont **** up, youll get shot")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Ready?")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Im not sorry.")
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,5))
    print("####__GO__####")
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    a = input()
    toc = time.perf_counter()
    timeSpent = toc-tic
    print(timeSpent)
    x + 1
```

I would like to take the value that is output from toc and tic (time.perf_counter) and record it so I can average the results to get a baseline reaction time.

How would I do this?

Comment: Sum the differences then divide by the number of iteration of your loop. No need to declare *x* outside the loop. *x + 1* has no effect on the running of this program

Comment: standard rule: if you use `for`-loop then you should use `list` to keep all results.

Comment: when you will have list with all results then `average = sum(results) / len(results)`